# Person Account Error: Your account record type is missing, a duplicate, or invalid. Ask your admin to check the individual record type

Tags: apex, trigger, health-cloud

We are using Salesforce Health Cloud and have Person Accounts Enabled.

When I create a person account, I see the following error:

```
HealthCloudGA.AccountTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: HealthCloudGA.MoiExceptionWrapper.ValidationException: Your account record type is missing, a duplicate, or invalid. Ask your admin to check the individual record type configurations in Setup. (System Code)
```

I am looking to understand why this is happening.

I reviewed the following support article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318117&type=1&mode=1

It says that

This error will be observed if:

- The 'Household' record type has been deactivated on the Account object
- The 'Individual' record type has been deactivated on the Account object
  The 'Individual' record type has been deactivated on the Contact object
- To resolve the above issues you need to reactivate the record types and consider removing access to the record types at the profile (or permission set) level.

This error will also be observed if there is an Account record type with a Name (DeveloperName) that matches to the Name (Developer Name) of a Person Account Record Type.

[image]

[image]

I clearly have access to all the record types needed. Not sure why this is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to look at the Individual Record Type Mapper.

Be sure that it's listed as follows:

> Label: Person Account
>
> Individual Record Type Mapper Name: PersonAccount
>
> Account Record Type: PersonAccount

Note the SPACE in Label and lack of space in the other two.